# Trying to edit a List in realm

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I'm trying to make a `List` with realm:

```
class TripsList : Object {
    let trips = List<Trip>()
}
```

Then, inside my ViewController class:

```
var trips : Results<TripsList>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trips = realm.objects(TripsList.self)

}
```

When someone moves a UITableViewRow, I want to update my realm database.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = self.realm.objects(Trip.self)[sourceIndexPath.row]

    trips.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    trips.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

}
```

Here are my TableView Datasource methods:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return realm.objects(Trip.self).count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.text = nameData.names[realm.objects(Trip.self)[indexPath.row].tripID]
    return cell
}
```

The problem is there is no option to do `trips.remove(at:)` or `trips.insert(_:at:)`.

My overall goal is the ability to insert and remove  when someone moves a UITableViewRow and update my realm database.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly modify a `Results` instance. `Results` are auto-updating collections, meaning that they always reflect the current state of the query you used to initialise them. You need to modify the `Realm` in order to modify the `Results` instance.

Moreover, a `Results` instance is only guaranteed to keep its ordering in case you sort it. So you'll need to introduce a property on `Trip` that you use to sort the objects and modify that property when the user moves a row.

Your `TripsList` class seems to be unnecessary, since it seems that you simply want to store a number of `Trip` objects in Realm, then retrieve them without actually doing any grouping. Even if you needed to group them, you could do so using Realm queries. Keeping this in mind, this is how I'd modify your current code to allow the user to sort their `Trip`s and save the sorting to `Realm`.

```
class Trip: Object {
    // Your existing code for Trip 
    ...
    // Sorting property
    @objc dynamic var sortingIndex = 0
}
```

In your table view controller:

```
var trips : Results<Trip>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    trips = realm.objects(Trip.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "sortingIndex")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return trips?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
    if let tripID = trips?[indexPath.row].tripID {
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameData.names[tripID]
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let movedObject = trips?.[sourceIndexPath.row] else { return }
    // Depending on your exact needs, you might want to update the `sortingIndex` property of your other rows as well, whose position in the table view was affected by the reordering
    try! realm.write {
        movedObject.sortingIndex = destinationIndexPath.row
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible if you could provide some example code for me to work with? That sounds a bit confusing.

Comment: @Callum if you update your question with the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, sure. Without more context, your mixed use of `TripsList`, which holds a `List<Trip>` and then simply querying all `Trip`s using `self.realm.objects(Trip.self)[sourceIndexPath.row]` is a bit misleading

Comment: there you go, @Dávid Pásztor

Comment: @Callum it still seems to me that you don't actually use `TripsList` for anything and you don't actually have a need for it. Do you simply want to store your `Trip` objects in Realm and display all trips in a table view, which the user can rearrange? What would you want to use `TripsList` for? If this is the case (that you don't actually need `TripsList`, I'll update my answer with an example code).

Comment: I did some research and It looked like I needed to create a new class to store a List. Thanks, code will be very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185835/discussion-between-callum-and-david-pasztor).

Comment: check the new message in chat please